# Why does GetPointCount of a GraphicsPath always return 0?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to learn the gdiplus windows API, and in particular how to use GraphicsPath to get points from different shapes. I noticed that I could never get anything to appear from microsoft's example code, so I tried to see how many points were actually in a GraphicsPath like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <iostream>

//use gdiplus library when compiling
#pragma comment( lib, "gdiplus" )

using namespace Gdiplus;

VOID GetPointCountExample()
{
    // Create a path that has one ellipse and one line.
    GraphicsPath path;
    path.AddLine(220, 120, 300, 160);

    // Find out how many data points are stored in the path.
    int count = path.GetPointCount();
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    GetPointCountExample();
}
```

This always returned a count of 0. Why is this?

I have tried compiling with mingw-64 and Visual Studio with the same result.

I also tried printing out the Gdiplus::Status returned from this:

```
GraphicsPath path;
int stat = path.StartFigure();

std::cout << stat << std::endl;
```

Which printed a status of 2, "InvalidParameter" even though StartFigure doesn't take parameters.

Comment: This isn't actually accessing the GDI+ API. It's using the API through C++ wrappers that are designed to work with Microsoft's compiler. Please use Microsoft's compiler to verify whether this works. Also note that `cout` is buffered. You should flush the stream before exiting the process. Are you perhaps misinterpreting the process' exit code as the program's output?

Comment: Oh right, how do you access the GDI+ API? I'll try compiling in a visual studio project today

Comment: [GDI+ Flat API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-flatapi-flat). Though, really, it's far easier to just output a `std::endl` to flush the output stream. The code, as written, probably simply never outputs anything.

Comment: Hmm interesting I'll try adding the endl too, but this code does print a 0 character to the terminal. Oo thanks for the link! I'll read up on the GDI+ Flat API too

Comment: @IInspectable I tried building with visual studio and adding std::endl and got the same result

Comment: @NO_GUI If you have resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh read more documentation and found this: `The GdiplusStartup function initializes Windows GDI+. Call GdiplusStartup before making any other GDI+ calls`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/Gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusstartup

This code works:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <iostream>

//use gdiplus library when compiling
#pragma comment( lib, "gdiplus" )

using namespace Gdiplus;

VOID GetPointCountExample()
{
    // Create a path that has one ellipse and one line.
    GraphicsPath path;
    path.AddLine(0, 0, 0, 1);

    // Find out how many data points are stored in the path.
    int count = path.GetPointCount();
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    //Must call GdiplusStartup before making any GDI+ calls
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/Gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusstartup
    ULONG_PTR token;
    GdiplusStartupInput input;
    input.GdiplusVersion = 1;
    input.SuppressBackgroundThread = false;

    GdiplusStartup(&token, &input, NULL);

    GetPointCountExample();

    //Shutdown GDI+ when finished using
    GdiplusShutdown(token);
}
```